# How to do proper validation for this and set focus and then form has to submitted

Tags: javascript

Here I am facing problem in if condition it validates for subject and unable to set focus and not validate for medium field. Here checkbox is coming from mysql. But it gives source like this only. can any figure out what is the problem in my code?what I have to do here.I hope everyone understand the question.I need to proper code to validate these two fields. At least in subject column any one should be selected likewise in regional field also any should be selected. I tried has much what I can do. But I could not completed the work.

what I needed is:

1. Atleast any one should be selected in subject field.if its null alert +focus
2. like wise for medium field also.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function check() {
        var a1 = false;
        b1 = false;
        var chk = document.getElementsByName('subject[]');
        var reg = document.getElementsByName('regional[]');
        var len = chk.length;
        var reg1 = reg.length;
        if (len) {
            for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                if (chk[i].checked) {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    alert('please select the subject');
                    a1 = true;
                }
            }
        }
        if (!chk[i].checked) {
            chk[i].focus();
        }
        if (len) {
            for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                if (reg1[i].checked) {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    alert('please select the medium');
                    b1 = true;
                }
            }
        }
        if (a1 == true && b1 == true) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    </script>

Myform is:
<form name="f1" action="s.php" method="post">
Subject
<input type='checkbox' name='subject[]' value='science'>science
<input type='checkbox' name='subject[]' value='maths'>maths<br/>

Medium
<input type='checkbox' name='regional[]' value='Hindi'>Hindi
<input type='checkbox' name='regional[]' value='english'>english<br/>

<input type="submit" name="land" class="butt" value="SUBMIT" onClick="return check();">
</form>
```

Comment: The else needs to be outside the loop

Comment: thanks can you do it and execute in jsfiddle beacuse past two days i am unable to do this.once again can write for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this

Instead of onclick use onsubmit and assign the function onload

```js
window.onload=function() {
    document.getElementsByName("f1")[0].onsubmit=function() {
      var chk = document.getElementsByName('subject[]'),chkOk=false;
      for (var i = 0, n=chk.length; i < n; i++) {
        if (chk[i].checked) {
          chkOk = true;
          break;
        }
      }
      console.log(chkOk)
      if (!chkOk) {
        alert('please select the subject');
        chk[0].focus(); // focus the first
        return false;
      }
      var reg = document.getElementsByName('regional[]'),regOk=false;
      for (var i = 0, n=reg.length; i < n; i++) {
        if (reg[i].checked) {
          regOk = true;
          break;
        }
      }
      if (!regOk) {
        alert('please select the medium');
        reg[0].focus(); // focus the first
        return false;
      }
      return true; // allow submit
   }
}
```

```html
<form name="f1" action="s.php" method="post" onsubmit="return check()">
Subject
<input type='checkbox' name='subject[]' value='science'>science
<input type='checkbox' name='subject[]' value='maths'>maths<br/>

Medium
<input type='checkbox' name='regional[]' value='Hindi'>Hindi
<input type='checkbox' name='regional[]' value='english'>english<br/>

<input type="submit" name="land" class="butt" value="SUBMIT">
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks here is an issue.If I selected subject also again it showing 'please select the subject'.

Comment: You got the concept. I am unable to embed in window.onload  or what about the chkok=true is not working

Comment: same thing I have change the function to window.onload. please this link http://vkacademy.in/res/wel.html

Comment: sorry I don't understand

Comment: I am using some html5 validation  required for some fields and rest of the function is user code.i merged both. because of required field validation it is not working? any solution for that. I have used required only for maximum four fields or any what is the solution to validate the subject and medium in html5. using required but it is checkbox group. help me

Comment: Please ask a new question